# Use parent as event sender

Tags: c#, events

I have a panel and on that panel there is a pictureBox and a label. What I'm trying to do is when I click on the label or the pictureBox, the event would read that the sender is panel.
Example code:

```
Panel panel1 = new Panel();
Label label1 = new Label();
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
panel1.Size = new Size(500,500);
this.Controls.Add(panel1);
label1.Text = "Some text";
panel1.Controls.Add(label1);
pb.Image = somePath;
panel1.Controls.add(pb);
panel1.Click += onClick;
label1.Click += onClick;
pb.Click += onClick;
```

The panel and everything is added in a loop.

```
private void onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(sender == panel1)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

This is the event method.

Comment: so where is the problem?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal and vaibhav problem is that sender element is panel or other control that Op want to check

Comment: @PranayRana, `sender == panel1` does the same work.
for this to happen, the `panel1` object should be global variable

Comment: @vaibhav - you need to check because sender is object either you convert or you can check you cannot do direct...

Comment: @Grega Menih, please give a more clear point of view for your question

Answer (score 2):

> What I'm trying to do is when I click on the label or the pictureBox, the event would read that the sender is panel.

What the `sender` is is entirely up to the code that is invoking the event. If it isn't the panel that is actually invoking it, then it is unlikely to present as such. In some cases (buttons, etc) there is a method exposed to cause the event to be invoked directly, but not here. Frankly, I think your best option might be:

```
panel1.Click += onClick;
label1.Click += (sender,args) => onClick(panel1,args);
pb.Click += (sender,args) => onClick(panel1,args);
```

i.e. forward it manually, spoofing the sender.

An even better approach might be to do something with the `.Tag`, or just have different handlers for different behaviours, rather than switching inside a single handler.

Answer (score 1):

[Read about **is** keyword on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) : The **is** operator is used to check whether the run-time type of an object is compatible with a given type.

you need to check that sender control is panel or not than you can do it by doing as follow ....

```
   if(sender is Panel )
```

or

```
  if(sender.GetType() == typeof(Panel)) 
  {
             //do something     
  }
```

Comment: the way I read it, the OP isn't trying to *test* what `sender` is - he wants it to *be* `panel1` even when coming from another control.

Comment: @MarcGravell - might be but that is not clear that y i suggested this solution...

Comment: @MarcGravell thats the problem...!!! the question asked isn't precise enough for us to get to a conclusion about what the asker wants.!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if(sender is Panel) 
{
    //Do Something     
} 
else if (sender is Label)
{
    //Do something
}
else if (sender is PictureBox)
{
    //Do somethin
}
```

Comment: the way I read it, the OP isn't trying to *test* what `sender` is - he wants it to *be* `panel1` even when coming from another control.